# Implicitly defined variables in Lisp and symbol tables

Tags: common-lisp

Suppose one introduces variables in a fresh Common Lisp
at the REPL and one types: `(setq q 2)`.

I understand from these columns that this variable `q` is
not defined following the Common Lisp standard and
depends upon the implementation.

My question is:  what is the easiest way or test to be
sure what it is exactly?

I read in one source that `q` is then automatically an implicitly defined
global dynamic variable and is then equivalent to
`(defpar q 2)`.

In relation with this question.  Seasoned Lisp
programmers talk much about the symbol tables.  I do
not find in e.g. Seibel how to find out what is in
those tables. Can one access these tables?  Do
debuggers support accessing these tables in a non
standard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SETQ` rather than `DEFPARAMETER` is likely to make a global variable, but not a special variable. That will cause annoying debugging later. Don't use `SETQ` to define variables.

An example with lengthy code snippets. I'm using non-standard SBCL for this.

Let's define a package with two variables, one defined with `DEFPARAMETER` and one set with `SETQ`.

```
CL-USER> (defpackage :foo (:use :cl))
#<PACKAGE "FOO">
CL-USER> (in-package :foo)
#<PACKAGE "FOO">
FOO> (defparameter q 2)
Q
FOO> (setq w 2)
; in: SETQ W
;     (SETQ FOO::W 2)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: W
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     W
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)
FOO> q
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)
FOO> w
2 (2 bits, #x2, #o2, #b10)
```

The warning message already tells us that SBCL doesn't like the `SETQ` option, but the variable seems to work. Let's try to `DESCRIBE` the variables:

```
FOO> (describe 'q)
FOO::Q
  [symbol]

Q names a special variable:
  Value: 2
; No values
FOO> (describe 'w)
FOO::W
  [symbol]

W names an undefined variable:
  Value: 2
; No values
```

This says that `Q` is a special variable, while `W` is an undefined variable.

```
FOO> (sb-cltl2:variable-information 'q)
:SPECIAL
NIL
NIL
FOO> (sb-cltl2:variable-information 'w)
NIL
NIL
NIL
```

This also confirms that `W` is not a special variable like `Q` is. So what does this mean? Let's define a function that uses those variables:

```
FOO> (defun foobar ()
       (format t "~&Q: ~a~%W: ~a~%" q w))

; in: DEFUN FOOBAR
;     (FORMAT T "~&Q: ~a~%W: ~a~%" FOO::Q FOO::W)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: W
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     W
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
FOOBAR
FOO> (foobar)
Q: 2
W: 2
NIL
```

Again we get warnings about `W`, but the code still seems to work. Let's try to shadow the variables.

```
FOO> (defun quux ()
       (let ((q 100)
             (w 100))
         (foobar)))
; in: DEFUN QUUX
;     (LET ((FOO::Q 100) (FOO::W 100))
;       (FOO::FOOBAR))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable W is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
QUUX
FOO> (quux)
Q: 100
W: 2
NIL
```

Now we notice that since `W` is not special, you can't shadow it. Also

```
FOO> (sb-introspect:who-binds 'q)
((QUUX
  . #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE
       :PATHNAME NIL
       :FORM-PATH (0 3 2)
       :FORM-NUMBER 0
       :CHARACTER-OFFSET 0
       :FILE-WRITE-DATE NIL
       :PLIST NIL
       :DESCRIPTION NIL)))
FOO> (sb-introspect:who-binds 'w)
NIL
```

We can't see who binds the variable. Or who sets either:

```
FOO> (defun qwerty ()
       (setf w 1000
             q 1000))

; in: DEFUN QWERTY
;     (SETF FOO::W 1000
;           FOO::Q 1000)
; --> PROGN SETF 
; ==>
;   (SETQ FOO::W 1000)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: W
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     W
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
QWERTY
FOO> (qwerty)
1000 (10 bits, #x3E8)
FOO> (sb-introspect:who-sets 'q)
((QWERTY
  . #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE
       :PATHNAME NIL
       :FORM-PATH (0 3 2)
       :FORM-NUMBER 0
       :CHARACTER-OFFSET 0
       :FILE-WRITE-DATE NIL
       :PLIST NIL
       :DESCRIPTION NIL)))
FOO> (sb-introspect:who-sets 'w)
NIL
```

Since you also asked about symbol tables, the easiest way to see what's in it is to `INSPECT` a package. You can do that with your IDE (in Slime C-c I) or by calling the function directly:

```
FOO> (inspect (find-package :foo))

The object is a STRUCTURE-OBJECT of type PACKAGE.
0. %NAME: "FOO"
1. %NICKNAMES: NIL
2. %USE-LIST: (#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP">)
3. TABLES: #(#<SB-INT:PACKAGE-HASHTABLE
               (978+0)/1973 [2.270 words/sym,load=49.6%] {100001A483}>)
4. MRU-TABLE-INDEX: 0
5. %USED-BY-LIST: NIL
6. INTERNAL-SYMBOLS: #<SB-INT:PACKAGE-HASHTABLE (7+0)/17 [2.732 words/sym,load=41.2%] {1006D60AE3}>
7. EXTERNAL-SYMBOLS: #<SB-INT:PACKAGE-HASHTABLE (0+0)/3 [load=0.0%] {1006D60B13}>
8. %SHADOWING-SYMBOLS: NIL
9. DOC-STRING: NIL
10. LOCK: NIL
11. %IMPLEMENTATION-PACKAGES: (#<PACKAGE "FOO">)
12. SOURCE-LOCATION: #S(SB-C:DEFINITION-SOURCE-LOCATION
                        :NAMESTRING NIL
                        :TOPLEVEL-FORM-NUMBER NIL
                        :FORM-NUMBER NIL
                        :PLIST NIL)
13. %LOCAL-NICKNAMES: NIL
14. %LOCALLY-NICKNAMED-BY: NIL
> 6

The object is a STRUCTURE-OBJECT of type SB-INT:PACKAGE-HASHTABLE.
0. CELLS: #(FOOBAR 0 QUUX ? 0 0 0 E W 0 Q QWERTY 0 0 0 0 0
            #(21 0 98 59 0 0 0 223 135 0 193 37 0 0 0 0 0))
1. SIZE: 12
2. FREE: 5
3. DELETED: 0
> 0

The object is a VECTOR of length 18.
0. FOOBAR
1. 0
2. QUUX
3. ?
4. 0
5. 0
6. 0
7. E
8. W
9. 0
10. Q
11. QWERTY
12. 0
13. 0
14. 0
15. 0
16. 0
17. #(21 0 98 59 0 0 0 223 135 0 193 37 0 0 0 0 0)
> 8

The object is a SYMBOL.
0. Name: "W"
1. Package: #<PACKAGE "FOO">
2. Value: 1000
3. Function: "unbound"
4. Plist: NIL
> u

The object is a VECTOR of length 18.
0. FOOBAR
1. 0
2. QUUX
3. ?
4. 0
5. 0
6. 0
7. E
8. W
9. 0
10. Q
11. QWERTY
12. U
13. 0
14. 0
15. 0
16. 0
17. #(21 0 98 59 0 0 0 223 135 0 193 37 201 0 0 0 0)
> 10

The object is a SYMBOL.
0. Name: "Q"
1. Package: #<PACKAGE "FOO">
2. Value: 1000
3. Function: "unbound"
4. Plist: NIL
> q
```

You could also use `DO-SYMBOLS` to loop over symbols in a package.

```
FOO> (do-symbols (symbol)
       (when (and (boundp symbol)
                  (eq (symbol-package symbol) *package*))
         (format t "~&~a~%  Value: ~a~%  Info: ~a~%  Who sets: ~a~%  ~
                    Who binds: ~a~%  Plist: ~a~%  Documentation: ~a~%~%"
                 symbol
                 (symbol-value symbol)
                 (multiple-value-list 
                  (sb-cltl2:variable-information symbol))
                 (sb-introspect:who-sets symbol)
                 (sb-introspect:who-binds symbol)
                 (symbol-plist symbol)
                 (documentation symbol 'variable))))
Q
  Value: 1000
  Info: (SPECIAL NIL NIL)
  Who sets: ((QWERTY
              . #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE
                   :PATHNAME NIL
                   :FORM-PATH (0 3 2)
                   :FORM-NUMBER 0
                   :CHARACTER-OFFSET 0
                   :FILE-WRITE-DATE NIL
                   :PLIST NIL
                   :DESCRIPTION NIL)))
  Who binds: ((QUUX
               . #S(SB-INTROSPECT:DEFINITION-SOURCE
                    :PATHNAME NIL
                    :FORM-PATH (0 3 2)
                    :FORM-NUMBER 0
                    :CHARACTER-OFFSET 0
                    :FILE-WRITE-DATE NIL
                    :PLIST NIL
                    :DESCRIPTION NIL)))
  Plist: NIL
  Documentation: NIL

W
  Value: 1000
  Info: (NIL NIL NIL)
  Who sets: NIL
  Who binds: NIL
  Plist: NIL
  Documentation: NIL
```

Comment: 'is likely to make a global variable, but not a special variable' - it's not likely, but CMUCL actually does that by default.